# How are "Great!" rating streaks tracked for "Clock Stopper"?

Tags: final-fantasy-13-2

The *Clock Stopper* achievement/trophy requires getting 100 consecutive "Great!" ratings on the Mog Clock. I've been grinding this out, but after 50 of them, I missed one.

Can I just reload an earlier save and pick up from there? Or is the streak counter tracked across all saves (i.e., I'm starting at 0 again no matter what I do)?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I decided to bite the bullet and test this myself, since it was going to be at least 50 more battles either way.

You can, in fact, start from an earlier saved game. I loaded up my save file that had 50 consecutive "Great!" streaks, and sure enough, after 50 more, the *Clock Stopper* trophy popped.

Comment: Note to self: Save after each ten consecutive.

Comment: For the most part, if you're grinding in Arclyte Steppe, it just sort of happens.  None of the monsters there start moving instantly, so it's simple to get "Great!".

Good test, though, Mark!

Comment: @fbueckert That's what I did: it worked well. Although that Blue Chocobo who caused the streak to break by running at me can go to hell.

Comment: @MarkTrapp Yeah, those blue chocobos suck.  Took me I don't know HOW many to finally get a crystal out of one.  Probably spent a good combined two-three hours doing nothing but.  And then ironically, after I got one, the very next one also gave me a crystal.